# Swift : Cannot assign to "" in self

Tags: swift

In Swift, I have a computed property called `managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext`. when I try to initialise it like:

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? {
    get {
        createManagedObjectContext()
        return self.managedObjectContext
    }
    set(newManagedObjectContext) {
        self.manageObjectContext = newManagedObjectContext
    }
}

func createManagedObjectContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {

    if let coordinator = persistentStorageCoordinator() as NSPersistentStoreCoordinator!
    {
        self.managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
        self.managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handleBackgroundMOCDidSaveNotification:", name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, object: self.managedObjectContext)
    }

    return self.managedObjectContext!;
}
```

I am getting an error saying : `Cannot assign to "managedObjectContext" in self`.

Can anybody help to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you creating a struct or class?

Comment: Could you show the rest of the class, it might help.

Comment: Yes, please show the setter for your computed property as a minimum

Comment: why you want a computed property? you getter/setter just call itself.

Comment: I want it to allow nil also.

Comment: That is what the ? at the end of the declaration says - this value may be unassigned

Comment: if you would not like to make further actions in setter but assigning the new value, you don't need computed setter for the `managedObjectContext`.

Answer (score 37):

You also receive this compile error when you're trying to assign a value to a `let` constant. Changing the variable's type to `var` should solve it, in this case.

Answer (score 8):

A lazy stored property (see the Swift Programming Language book, page 313) is more appropriate for what you are trying to do here.

```
lazy var managedObjectContext = createManagedObjectContext()
```

`createManagedObjectContext()` won't be called until you attempt to access the property the first time (and only the first time).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using a computed property as if it were a standard property, you are effectively attempting to call the setter recursively .  You don't need to use a computed property here, just a standard property -

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
```

A computed property is one whose value is computed when required based on other properties - For example the "center" property in the *Swift Programming Language* -

```
var center: Point {
    get {
        let centerX = origin.x + (size.width / 2)
        let centerY = origin.y + (size.height / 2)
        return Point(x: centerX, y: centerY)
    }
    set(newCenter) {
        origin.x = newCenter.x - (size.width / 2)
        origin.y = newCenter.y - (size.height / 2)
    }
 }
```

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itunes.apple.com/au/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11

Center is determined by the origin and size, and setting the center affects the origin

Answer (score 1):

Add it!! = )

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.YOURNAME_OTHERS.YOURAPP" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("YOURAPP", withExtension: "momd")
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("YOURAPP.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError.errorWithDomain("YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            //abort()
        }
    }
}
```